# *Python* Non-Recursive Functions and Strings

Tags: python, string, recursion

we have just begun our unit on recursion, and I had a question regarding **non-recursive** functions and **strings**

I understand that strings are inherently recursive, as each **character** within a string has its own positive or negative **index** value, but I am a little unclear on how to create this function.

EDIT: **Please disregard above text**

What I meant to say:

I understand that a **sequence** is recursive in nature, that a **string** is a character followed by another string, just as a **list** is an element followed by another **list.**

Imagine we had a function called:

```
def flipside(s)
```

And when we input a string into our **s** parameter of the function, for example, the string:

```
'homework'
```

It takes the **first half** of the string (s) and moves it to the back **while** taking the **second half** of the string moving it the front, effectively generating the output:

```
'workhome'
```

I guess what I am having an issue with, is regarding string operations. If I do not know the **length** of s because it can take on any value due to it being a parameter, how do I create a **non-recursive** program to take 1//2 of s and move that half of the string to the back while **simultaneously** pushing the second half forward.

I have only gone so far as to set my base case:

```
def flipside(s):
    if s == (''):
        return 0
    else:
        fliprest = 
        return fliprest
```

Thank you, I would appreciate any information on the thought process behind your logic, or any feedback regarding any bad habits that I may be developing with how I have started off my code.

Comment: "I understand that strings are inherently recursive, as each character within a string has its own positive or negative index value" -- I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Is the question how to ask Python what the length of a string is? It's not clear what specific technical problem is preventing you from implementing your program without needing to recurse; note that Stack Overflow questions should be narrow and specific.

Comment: Are you asking for a recursive, or non-recursive solution? Because a non-recursive one doesn't have a base case. Also, you seem to be conflating recursive functions and the "recursive nature" of strings - the fact that single characters are also strings.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that made no sense, I have created a new paragraph explaining what I meant initially. I think I poorly worded my explanation, my problem is that I am trying to create a function that swaps the first half and second half of string. I am unclear on the rules of non-recursive functions and I did  not know if it would require extra steps beyond just having a base case. Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slicing

```
def flipside(s):
    return s[len(s)//2:] + s[:len(s)//2]

>>> flipside('homework')
'workhome'
```